# Chkdsk Questions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, command-line, chkdsk

Recently in running `chkdsk /r` on my system drive (platter drive, Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) I've gotten back results like:

```
4 EA records processed
76 reparse records processed
```

Am I right in assuming these aren't problematic reports?  Do most NTFS system drives report back EA and reparse records processed when chkdsk is run?

Comment: Yes is the short answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly normal for a `chkdsk` report.

Answer (score 64):

**EA Records** are Extended Attribute records. They're a feature of NTFS that allows for a file to have custom extra metadata stored along with it (metadata that is not interpretable to the file system). EA records are a somewhat obscure feature of NTFS that are used very infrequently, but having a few of them doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with your filesystem.

As an interesting side note, EA records are actually intended to support the emulation of OS/2, an early Microsoft operating system that is still used in some legacy systems (support officially ended 2006). Wikipedia notes that some Windows POSIX layers use EA records to store unix permissions fields.

**Reparse Records** establish Reparse Points within your file system. Reparse Points are a very interesting feature of NTFS that allow a file to be tagged with some data that will essentially result in a program (an FS Filter, sort of like a driver) being run every time you access the file. They're not used a lot, most notably they are used to create symlinks in Windows (via the `mklink` command) and for volume mount points (this is an obscure feature of Windows that allows you to mount a device as a folder in another device, somewhat like the Unix file system). A normal Windows install will have a number of them that are set up by the installer.

***tl;dr:*** these entries both refer to infrequently used features of NTFS, which is why there's a small number of occurrences of each. They don't indicate any kind of problem with your file system or operating system.

Comment: Great info.  I just felt that the other answer more specifically addressed "yes" or "no".

Comment: +1 for teaching me what an EA Record is. Thanks!

Comment: I always like over-explaining things, I find the internal workings of the OS very interesting so I talk about them a lot.

Comment: @Lil'Smokey If that's the case, you should accept this one as the best answer.

Comment: Any idea on how to identify the files that have the EA records?

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly OK.

Extended attributes and reparse points aren't exactly widely used by programs, but they are *completely normal*. Nothing to worry about here. :)