# chkdsk: What are large files and EA records?

Tags: chkdsk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chkdsk Questions](https://superuser.com/questions/292338/chkdsk-questions)

When running chkdsk I often see some info re: large files and EA records?
What are they?

```
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage
  35072 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  14 large file records processed
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
```

Comment: it answers my EA query, what about large files? > 2GB?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but large files may be those whose allocation information is too large to fit within a single base file record in the MFT.