# How can I view an "EA Record" (presumably part of the MFT in NTFS)?

Tags: ntfs, forensics

I recently ran into a situation where a failing USB hub caused an external hard drive to not "safely disconnect." In the process of repairing the drive to avoid having Windows see it as a RAW filesystem, I noticed that the chkdsk utility processed several thousand "EA Records". As [@jcrawford](https://superuser.com/users/42428/jcrawfordor) kindly explains in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/292349/8811), these are Extended Attribute records which allow NTFS to store metadata.

I used to work for a company that used a Windows file server to store Macintosh files, and vaguely remember the software we used would store proprietary Mac file data in NTFS [alternate data streams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105763). At first I thought this might have been the same thing, but it does not appear so.

It seems that EA records are rarely used, at least from cursory searches to understand them better. As such, most users have few of them. Since I have thousands on my drive, I am curious what files they are associated with and what they contain.

**By what means can I find files that have EA Records in the MFT, and how can I most readily view them?**